# How can I find out what functions are deprecated

Tags: linux, x11

I am trying to update an old X11/Motif application to use modern objects and libraries. I used ldd to get a list of all the shared objects being used, but I am trying to figure out what functions in particular link to those libraries so I can remove the deprecated functions. Any ideas? Thanks

In particular (but not limited to), libXp.so.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what functions are in libXp.so.6, try:

```
nm -D --defined-only /usr/lib/libXp.so.6
```

Now you can see that they all start with Xp, except for a few weird ones that probably aren't meant to be in the public API.

Your simplest approach is probably to just use grep to search for Xp, or a regex like `Xp[A-Za-z]+`, in the source code.

Comment: I will give it a try, but I know I am not using any functions that begin with Xp. I think another library I am linking to uses it though. It seems to be a mine field.

Comment: That helped figure out exactly what was used. In combination with ldd I was able to figure out what functions and dependencies were needed and why. Now I just have to remove them... Thanks!